# Parse.com powered db for an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios7, parse-platform

I have a quiz app which uses Parse.com for some data storage, app has a local sqlite database to store quiz related data. Now I want to store all the quiz database on Parse and download and store it into sqlite when the app runs first time. How is it possible and what is the best way to do that.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing on Parse? Do you just want to have an update-able collection of questions and answers or is there also data your users will be editing/adding to? Also, what functionality do you want your app to have offline?

Comment: I want to store all questions/ answers and related pdf files on Parse So that if something gets changed I can sync it local DB. Currently I am storing user's scoring record on Parse. I want to get questions from Parse for the first time app runs or if there is an update on Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case it may be possible to rely largely on the Parse cache. As Alexandre pointed out in his answer, accessing the cache is a matter of setting the `cachePolicy` of your `PFQuery` correctly. However, keep in mind that you don't have control over this cache. According to the Parse docs:

> Parse takes care of automatically flushing the cache when it takes up
>   too much space.

You will have to do some testing with your actual data and see if you run into the limitations of the Parse cache. You may also run into limitations with your pdf files. I imagine you would store these on Parse as PFFiles. PFFiles are caches on your local device, but again, you don't have full control over when those caches are deleted and you probably have to test the limits of this system. You can always fall back to re-downloading missing data.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use sqlite instead of cache/
You can use for example:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork;
```

Comment: Can we use it a whole DB ? And what if a user kills an app.